# Properties file value is not being read in xml

Tags: java, spring

I was learning Java Spring and faced a problem while working with properties file. Property File value is not being read in xml file and throwing exception.

The XML file is as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>


 <bean id="triangle1" class="com.springtest.shapes.Triangle">
  <property name="pointA" ref="zeroPoint"/>
  <property name="pointB" ref="point2" />
  <property name="pointC" ref="point3" />
 </bean>



 <bean id="zeroPoint" class="com.springtest.shapes.Point">
  <property name="x" value="#{pointA.pointX}" />
  <property name="y" value="#{pointA.pointY}" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="point2" class="com.springtest.shapes.Point">
  <property name="x" value="5" />
  <property name="y" value="2" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="point3" class="com.springtest.shapes.Point">
  <property name="x" value="-20" />
  <property name="y" value="10" />
 </bean>
 
 <bean class="com.springtest.main.DisplayNameBeanPostProcessor"/>
 
 <bean class="org.SpringFramework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations">
  <value>classpath:pointconfig.properties</value>
  </property>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

The Property file is as follows:

```css
pointA.pointX=0
pointA.pointY=0
```

The following exception is being shown:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'pointA' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:100)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:87)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:52)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:111)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:270)
at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:163)
... 28 more
```

The Project Structure is also provided
[image: project structure]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I finally get the answer after continuous digging. Thanks Manish Shen from Youtube.

My Problem was,

1. I named the class name wrong. This class name was used in previous version of spring. The new class name is "org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer".
2. The Value in the property of spring.xml should be written as "${pointA.pointX}" instead of "#{pointA.pointX}".

I am sharing the screenshot from where i got the answer.
[image]